# ms sql list of tables which do not have update permissions

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to get list of tables in a given database and a given schema which do not have update permissions for a given user.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work.

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/02/09/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-View-all-permissions--_2800_2_2900_.aspx

based on this i have modified a script and added object type descirption to the list which displays table for user, object , permission type , permission

so you can add where caluse to filter to user_table objects , filter further by user and permission type

```
declare @type_desc varchar(100)
declare @user varchar(100)


WITH    perms_cte as

(

        select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,

                dp.principal_id,

                dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,

                p.class_desc,

                OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,

                o.type_desc,

                p.permission_name,

                p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc

        from    sys.database_permissions p

        inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp


        on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id

        inner join sys.objects o

        on o.object_id =p.major_id

)

--users

SELECT p.principal_name,  p.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.[object_name], p.type_desc,p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc, cast(NULL as sysname) as role_name
--select *
FROM    perms_cte p

WHERE   principal_type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'

UNION

--role members

SELECT rm.member_principal_name, rm.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.object_name, p.type_desc,p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc,rm.role_name

FROM    perms_cte p

right outer JOIN (

    select role_principal_id, dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc, member_principal_id,user_name(member_principal_id) as member_principal_name,user_name(role_principal_id) as role_name--,*

    from    sys.database_role_members rm

    INNER   JOIN sys.database_principals dp

    ON     rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id

) rm

ON     rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id

order by 1
```

another useful link
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2132/auditing-sql-server-user-and-role-permissions-for-databases/